# Merge intersecting items in a list of lists

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, merge

I have list of lists where i would like to merge all lists which contain identical values and make a new list out of the merged lists using linq. Here's and example:

```
var animalGroups = new List<List<Animal>>{    
    new List<Animal>{lizard,cat,cow,dog},
    new List<Animal>{horse, chicken, pig, turkey},
    new List<Animal>{ferret,duck,cat,parrot},
    new List<Animal>{chicken,sheep,horse,rabbit}
   };
```

The desired output would be a new `List<List<animal>>` containing the following `List<Animal>`:

```
{lizard, cat, cow, dog, ferret, duck, parrot} 
{horse,  chicken, pig, turkey, sheep, rabbit}
```

I'm rather new to linq and i got stuck at grouping the intersected lists without creating duplicates.

Comment: So... group the input lists by which of them share any values, and them merge the groups each into their own list?

Comment: what is your rule for grouping ? all even index lists in one list, all odd index lists in the other?=!

Comment: What if more than 2 lists intersect with each other? I don't understand the rule which lists belong into one new.

Comment: @Rawling That is exactly what i want to achieve, but i failed to write such a querry.

Comment: @CareCat: what if a list contains only animals that are not contained in an other list, this list should be excluded from the result list because it's a non-sharing list?

Comment: @TimSchmelter If more then two lists intersect they should all be merged into one list. I'm sorry i forgot to mention that, but it shouldn't be a problem where i'm implementing the code.

To answer your second question: I'm not really trying to prevent something. I'm selecting objects from a program, and i want the selections which intersect to be handled as a single selection further down in the code.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Lists where no animals intersect should be left out. I didn't think of this because it shouldn't be the case where i'm implenting the code, but if such a list was included it would produce errors.

Comment: You're looking for a "connected component" or "set consolidation" algorithm: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Set_consolidation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the possible output with list of strings

```
    var animalGroups = new List<List<string>>
    {
        new List<string> {"lizard", "cat", "cow", "dog"},
        new List<string> {"horse", "chicken", "pig", "turkey"},
        new List<string> {"ferret", "duck", "cat", "parrot"},
        new List<string> {"chicken", "sheep", "horse", "rabbit"}
    };

    List<List<string>> mergedList = new List<List<string>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < animalGroups.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < animalGroups.Count; j++)
        {
            if (animalGroups[i].Intersect(animalGroups[j]).Any())
            {
                mergedList.Add(animalGroups[i].Concat(animalGroups[j]).Distinct().ToList());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @CareCat you say in the comments *If more then two lists intersect they should all be merged into one list* but this won't do that.

Comment: Do not work if I consider "If more then two lists intersect they should all be merged into one list"

Answer (score 1):

First, remember to override `Equals` and `GetHahCode` and/or implement `IEquatable<Animal>` in your `Anymial` class meaningfully(f.e. by comparing the Name).

```
List<IEnumerable<Animal>> mergedLists = animalGroups.MergeIntersectingLists().ToList();
```

Following extension method used which works with any type:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> MergeIntersectingLists<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> itemLists, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null) 
{
    if (comparer == null) comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

    var itemListDict = new Dictionary<T, HashSet<T>>(comparer);
    foreach (IEnumerable<T> sequence in itemLists)
    {
        IList<T> list = sequence as IList<T> ?? sequence.ToList();
        HashSet<T> itemStorage = null;
        list.FirstOrDefault(i => itemListDict.TryGetValue(i, out itemStorage));
        // FirstOrDefault will initialize the itemStorage because its an out-parameter
        bool partOfListIsContainedInOther = itemStorage != null;

        if (partOfListIsContainedInOther)
        {
            // add this list to the other storage (a HashSet that removes duplicates)
            foreach (T item in list)
                itemStorage.Add(item);
        }
        else
        {
            itemStorage = new HashSet<T>(list, comparer);
            // each items needs to be added to the dictionary, all have the same storage
            foreach (T item in itemStorage)
                itemListDict.Add(item, itemStorage); // same storage for all
        }
    }

    // Distinct removes duplicate HashSets because of reference equality
    //  needed because item was the key and it's storage the value
    //  and those HashSets are the same reference
    return itemListDict.Values.Distinct();  
}
```

Comment: Does this cover the case where a third list joins together two previously-separate lists?

Comment: @Rawling: if a third list contains an item that was already contained in a previous list, then all items of this list will go into that list(duplicates are removed). If the second list contained items of the first, the second is merged with the first. So at the end you will have a single list because all three shared at least one item

Comment: If you have "AB" and "CD" you will have [A] -> "AB", [B] -> "AB", [C] -> "CD", [D] -> "CD" (with the sets shared rather than duplicates). IF you add "BC", will you not end up with  [A] -> "ABC", [B] -> "ABC", [C] -> "CD", [D] -> "CD"?

Comment: I find it really hard to word these kinds of questions correctly. This answer is probably the most correct one for what i actually wrote, while the simpler answer using strings i marked as correct is exactly what i was after. I will work on asking more clear questions.

Comment: @Rawling: `AB`, `AB` and `CD` are single items and there are 4 lists in the main list, the first two have equal items and the last two have equal items. Then you want to add `BC` to the last list which contained only `CD` before, is that correct? I find it pretty hard to understand your sample. The expected result would be a list that contains following two lists: `[A]`-> `AB`, `[B]`-> `CD`, `BC` and the method should return that.

Comment: @CareCat: the extension method works the same with strings or any other type(including value types). If you take [Abhay's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46361466/284240) sample data this returns the result: `List<IEnumerable<string>> mergedLists = animalGroups.MergeIntersectingLists().ToList();`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Sorry, I meant the "AB" as collections of characters 'A' and 'B'. Got tired of typing out sets.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is *vague* one; in case you want to combine `0, 2, 4, ... 2n` as well as `1, 3, 5, ... 2n - 1` lists and you are looking for *Linq* solution:

```
  // I don't have Animal class, that's why I've put string
  // Be sure that Animal implements Equals as well as GetHashCode methods
  var animalGroups = new List<List<string>> {
    new List<string> {"lizard", "cat", "cow", "dog"},
    new List<string> {"horse", "chicken", "pig", "turkey"},
    new List<string> {"ferret", "duck", "cat", "parrot"},
    new List<string> {"chicken", "sheep", "horse", "rabbit"}
  };

  var result = animalGroups
    .Select((list, index) => new {
      list = list,
      index = index, })
     .GroupBy(item => item.index % 2, // grouping 0, 2, ... 2n as well as 1, 3,... 2n - 1 
              item => item.list)
     .Select(chunk => chunk
        .SelectMany(c => c)
        .Distinct()
        .ToList())
     .ToList();
```

Let's visualize the `result`:

```
  string test = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
    .Select(list => string.Join(", ", list)));

  Console.WritelLine(test);
```

Outcome

```
lizard, cat, cow, dog, ferret, duck, parrot
horse, chicken, pig, turkey, sheep, rabbit
```